# Context in Android Programming

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Context in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android)

Can anybody please tell me about the "context" term used in android. I wonder what exactly this means because this is something i used to see at lots of places.

I found it being a Class :- "Interface to global information about an application environment" but I am not quite clear regarding it still by now.

for Instance: 
          public GetCurrentLocation(Context context)
          {
        this.context = context;
          }

Thanks,
david

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/whats-context-in-android/3572553#3572553)

this.context = context is written confusingly. Another way to write the same:

```
public class LocationClass {

private Context context_belonging_to_class = null;

// ..

public GetCurrentLocation(Context context_from_call_entity) {
  context_belonging_to_class = context_from_calling_entity; // initializing context variable
}

// ..

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped me a bit to understand the context classes in a better way.